# Tool for batch processing EPS to JPG

Tags: image-processing, command-line, batch-file, adobe, postscript

Does anyone know of a adobe command line tool for creating jpegs from pdfs. This needs to cater for EPS 15 ( CS5 )?

I am converting EPS files to hi-res JPEGS with imagemagic but the results are mediocre even when the EPS is scanned at a very high-res. I think imagemagic works off the eps preview rather than rasterizing the vector.

GIMP is a bit better but not perfect.

Photoshop produces perfect jpegs but I dont know of a command line utility for this and have used the scripting tools but found them a pain on large batches.

I have distiller server but this ( to my knowledge ) does not produce jpegs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.adobe.com/eeurope/products/indesignserver.html does the Job.

Answer (score 3):

You could try ghostscript:

```
gs -sDEVICE=ppmraw -sOutputFile=file%d.ppm -r600 -dNOPAUSE yourfile.ps -c quit
```

Answer (score 2):

I would give **GraphicsMagick** http://www.graphicsmagick.org a try. It's a fork of Image Magick, more complete and updated.

It internally uses GhostScript as the PS interpreter, it does not use the embedded image but it completely renders the postscript.

For best results, make sure that you work at the right density. Instead of the PostScript standard of 72 DPI, try

```
gm convert -density 144 infile.eps outfile.jpg
```

with different `-density` values and see if the quality improves.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This did quite a good job on eps8 but eps10 were a bit shaky and often hung indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

If you're out of luck to find a command line tool for this, you can create a macro to script GIMP or Photoshop to do the job.

You have not mentioned the operating system, but if you're using OS X you can write an [AppleScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript) which will do the converting through commanding the GUI programs.

In Windows you can download a macro recorder program, but I have no experience with that in the new versions of Windows.

Comment: could use script-fu but the quality of the rendering is too low

Comment: I don't really get you because you could use those programs which are producing the best quality.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.reaconverter.com/command-line-image-processing.html for 50USD

Answer (score 0):

[Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org) is a mature free vector graphics program with commandline import/export options. I would be happy to test its ability to handle EPS15 but I don't have CS5 or any documents in that format. If you can post a link I'll try it out.